# How to connect to a service on a local network machine whch which only listens to localhost?

Tags: windows, networking, linux-networking, localhost

I have a service which only listens to localhost on port 7400.

There is a service running on a windows and an ubuntu machine on a private network.

How can another computer on the same network communicate with those services? I have read that binding/loopback may be an option [according to this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/34879/binding-the-rdp-listener-to-127-0-0-1-only)?

I am also confused how the binding takes place as I have seen it done using iptables on linux.

Is binding the best approach? Are there other alternatives? How can binding be achieved on windows/ubuntu?

Comment: why is it listening on localhost? - what protocol?

Comment: It's a service listening to instructions from the computer. I am hoping to send instructions to it from the network. The protocol is TCP.

Comment: oh ok - you can use 'something else' in the middle